# Handling the hotkey for menu item

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a new menu item "**Extra**" and add it to the window's main menu.

```
HMENU menu = GetMenu(hWnd);
HMENU popup = CreatePopupMenu();
AppendMenu(menu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)popup, L"Extra");
SetMenu(hWnd, popup);
```

Next I inserted new item to "**Extra**" item with hotkey:

```
#define IDM_ITEM1 12310
```

and:

```
MENUITEMINFOW mmi;
mmi.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFOW);
mmi.fMask = MIIM_STRING | MIIM_ID;
mmi.fType = MFT_STRING;
mmi.dwTypeData = L"First item\tCtrl+N";
mmi.wID = IDM_ITEM1;
InsertMenuItemW(popup, 1, true, &mmi);
```

[image]

And handle "**First item**" click:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
        case IDM_ITEM1:
        {
        MessageBox(0, L"First", L"", MB_OK);
        break;
        }
    }

break;
}
```

And now when I click on "First item" a message box is appeared.

But when I press **Ctrl+N** hotkey - nothing happens. Why? How to fix this (without using accelerator resources)?

Comment: Simply adding `Ctrl+N` to the menu item's caption doesn't activate hot key support. You have to write code to handle that. Adding a shortcut to a menu item will add the relevant text for you. Not the other way around.

Comment: @RemyLebeau can you post example?

Comment: [CGi03's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73504417/65863) shows how

Answer (score 1):

> without using accelerator resources ?

You need to create an array of ACCEL and then call the [CreateAcceleratorTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createacceleratortablea)   function:

```
ACCEL s_accel[2] = {{FCONTROL | FVIRTKEY, TEXT('C'), IDM_COLOR}, 
                    {FCONTROL | FVIRTKEY, TEXT('Q'), IDM_QUIT}};
HACCEL h_accel = CreateAcceleratorTable(s_accel, 2);

MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
  if (!TranslateAccelerator(hwnd, h_accel, &msg))
      {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
      }
}
DestroyAcceleratorTable(h_accel);
```

Comment: thanks! But I have another one requiremets: my code will be loaded from the dll and therefore this solution is not suitable. Is it possible to add an accelerator to an existing array at runtime?

Comment: @Ig_M The code that runs the window's message loop must create the accelerator table and call `TranslateAccelerator()` to process the table. So, if the DLL is going to define the menu items and accelerators, the main code will need a way to ask the DLL for those entries.